# How do we know that an NFA has a minimum amount of states?

Tags: nfa

Is there some kind of proof for this?  How can we know that the current NFA has the minimum amount?

Comment: Your post probably was marked down, because of lack of detail in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As opposed to [DFA minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization), where efficient methods exist to not only determine the size of, but actually compute, the smallest DFA in terms of number of states that describes a given regular language, no such general method is known for determining the size of a smallest NFA. Moreover, unless P=[PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE), no polynomial-time algorithm exists to compute a minimal NFA to recognize a language, as the following decision problem is [PSPACE-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE-complete):

> Given a DFA *M* that accepts the regular language *L*, and an integer *k*, is there an NFA with ≤ *k* states accepting *L*?

(Jiang & Ravikumar 1993).

There is, however, a simple theorem from Glaister and Shallit that can be used to determine lower bounds on the number of states of a minimal NFA:

> Let *L* ⊆ Σ<sup>*</sup> be a regular language and suppose that there exist *n* pairs *P* = { (*x*<sub>*i*</sub>, *w*<sub>*i*</sub>) | 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n* } such that:
>
> 1. *x*<sub>*i*</sub> *w*<sub>*i*</sub> ∈ *L* for 1 ≤ *i* ≤ *n*
> 2. *x*<sub>*j*</sub> *w*<sub>*i*</sub> ∉ *L* for 1 ≤ *j*, *i* ≤ *n* and *j* ≠ *i*
>
> Then any NFA accepting *L* has at least *n* states.

See:  Ian Glaister and Jeffrey Shallit (1996). "[A lower bound technique for the size of nondeterministic finite automata](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eshallit/Papers/nfa.ps)". *Information Processing Letters* **59** (2), pp. 75–77. DOI:[10.1016/0020-0190(96)00095-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2896%2900095-6).

Comment: OK, so polynomial time or space is not possible. What if we aren't concerned with performance. Surely there is an exhaustive algorithm, no? PSPACE-complete doesn't mean unsolvable, right?

Comment: @Brent: Correct, PSPACE-complete does not mean unsolvable (after all, [TQBF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TQBF) is solvable by a recursive algorithm). However, in this case, the claim that no such general method is known for determining the smallest NFA comes from the Glaister & Shallit paper. See also "[Computational complexity of NFA minimization for finite and unary languages](http://www.hermann-gruber.com/data/lata07-final.pdf)" by Hermann Gruber and Markus Holzer.

Comment: Note that the Glaister-Shallit lower bound (also known as the fooling-set method in computational complexity, and a special case of more general computational complexity lower bounds on NFA sizes) is not tight. Unfortunately, it could be that the biggest possible fooling set P has n elements, but the minimal NFAs have $2^O(n)$ states.